# Managed database or docker image with data-volume?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, docker, deployment, rails

I've mostly used managed database (AWS RDS) for production. I was fiddling with docker and was wondering if it's a good idea to have containerised postgres database with data-volume?

I feel it may not be a good idea, maybe because, I'm used to convenience of using managed database in production, but would like to know community opinion on this.

My docker-compose.yml looks like following:

```
version: '3'
services:

  rails-api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - gem_cache:/gems
    depends_on:
      - database
    networks:
      - vilio-network
    env_file:
      - .env/production

  redis:
    image: redis

  database:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - vilio-network
    env_file:
      - .env/production
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

networks:
  vilio-network:

volumes:
  db_data:
  gem_cache:
```

Thank you

Comment: Using a managed service and running a database in a container locally are very different scenarios; I'm not sure how you reconcile the two. What is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I agree. I'm just trying to build a MVP(hobby project) from scratch. I'm thinking of going with managed DB, as setting up everything looks a lot heck of task.